# How should I store 'extra' information in a td element?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following markup displayed to the end user:

```
<td class="event-start"> Mon 25th Feb (2013) @ 01:00pm</td>
```

and I am developing a feature that allows the user to edit the event start time.

However, this time format is awkward to work (in jQuery) with because I've formatted it for the end user rather than it being displayed as a unix timestamp.

So, I thought it may be more appropriate to store the actual value of the event-start (as a Unix Timestamp) in another attribute of the `<td>`element e.g.

```
<td class="event-start" actual-start="unix-timestamp"> Mon 25th Feb (2013) @ 01:00pm</td>
```

My question is - what should the name of this attribute be? Is there a standard name that I should use for this attribute or any conventions that I should follow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should research HTML5 Custom Data Attributes.  W3C documentation at the [HTML5 Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#custom-data-attribute).

In short, prefix your attribute name as `data-`.  Doing so gives dedicated access to your data element via JS `dataset` property on the element.

[This article](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/customattributes.shtml) has a pretty good explanation/examples:

In particular:

> The appeal of custom attributes is that it lets you easily associate
>   tidbits of information with an element, to be parsed later using
>   JavaScript for example. There are two ways to retrieve the value of
>   "data" attributes using JavaScript: the first is via the good old
>   fashion getAttribute() method of JavaScript, and the second, by
>   accessing the "dataset" property of the element.

Re compatibility, refer http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset which suggests *all* current browsers have *partial* support, while *most* current browsers have full support.  Where "full support" means the attributes can be accessed by the "dataset" property.

But importantly,

> All browsers can already use data-* attributes and access them using getAttribute.

Comment: @Sheldon, thanks for the accept, much appreciated.  Note, updated answer with additional notes re compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

> what should the name of this attribute be? Is there a standard name that I should use for this attribute or any conventions that I should follow?

it should be [data](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) attribute

```
<td class="event-start" data-actual-start="unix-timestamp">
```

The data attribute is supported in all major browsers. and jquery has its own method to manipulate the data attributes easily.. [doc here](http://api.jquery.com/data/)...